# Rolling Window on Dataframe, mutliple columns input and output

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a function myfunc, which does calculations on two pandas DataFrame columns. Output is a Numpy array.

```
def myfunc(df, args):
    import numpy
    return numpy.array([df.iloc[:,args[0]].sum,df.iloc[:,args[1]].sum])
```

This function is called within rolling_df_apply:

```
def rolling_df_apply(df, myfunc, window, *args):
    import pandas
    result = pandas.concat(pandas.DataFrame(myfunc(df.iloc[i:window+i],args), index=[df.index[i+window-1]]) for i in xrange(0,len(df)-window+1))
    return result
```

Running this via

```
import numpy
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(5,size=(5,2)))
window=3
args = [0,1]
result = rolling_df_apply(df, myfunc, window, *args)
```

gives ValueError within pandas.concat(): Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 1).
What must be changed to get this running?
Which indices imply shape 1,1? Shape of all dataframes to concatenate should be 1,2, though.

Answer (score 0):

- In `myfunc`, `.sum` should be `.sum()` in `myfunc`.
- Since `myfunc` returns an array of length 2,

  ```
  pandas.DataFrame(myfunc(df.iloc[i:window+i],args), index=[df.index[i+window-1]])
  ```

  is essentially the same as

  ```
  pd.DataFrame([0,1], index=[0])
  ```

  which raises

  ```
  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 1)
  ```

  The error is saying that the value `[0,1]` implies 1 row and 2 columns, 
  while the index implies 1 row and 1 column.

  On way to fix this would be to pass a dict instead of a list:

  ```
  In [191]: pd.DataFrame({'a':0,'b':1}, index=[0])
  Out[191]: 
     a  b
  0  0  1
  ```

So, to fix your code with minimal changes,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunc(df, args):
    return {'a':df.iloc[:,args[0]].sum(), 'b':df.iloc[:,args[1]].sum()}

def rolling_df_apply(df, myfunc, window, *args):

    frames = [pd.DataFrame(myfunc(df.iloc[i:window+i],args), 
                           index=[df.index[i+window-1]]) 
              for i in xrange(0,len(df)-window+1)]
    result = pd.concat(frames)
    return result

np.random.seed(2015)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(5,2)))
window=3
args = [0,1]

result = rolling_df_apply(df, myfunc, window, *args)   
print(result)
```

yields

```
   a  b
2  7  6
3  7  5
4  3  3
```

However, **it would be much more efficient** to replace `myfunc` and `rolling_df_apply` with a call to `pd.rolling_sum`:

```
result = pd.rolling_sum(df, window=3).dropna(axis=0)
```

yields the same result.